# Clear my view page when I hit finish button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a simple Queuing system my button `BtnNext()` dequeue the data that has been enqueued and render it on my view and on my CallScreen view.

Here is my button for `BtnNext()`

```
  public ActionResult BtnNext()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();
        MyQueue.todayQueue.Count();
        TempData["QueueItem"] = first;
        TempData.Keep();
        return PartialView("_queuenumber");
    }
```

when I hit the `BtnNext()` it will render the Dequeued data from my CallScreen view and its auto refreshing every 1 sec.

But my problem is I need to hit the `BtnFinish()` button to clear my CallScreen view and display nothing, right now its just displaying the previous `QueueNumber`, I want it to be cleared out.

Here is my Controller for my `BtnFinish()`

```
public PartialViewResult BtnFinish()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
    MyQueue.todayQueue.Count();
    TempData.Keep();
    return PartialView("_finish");
}
```

Here is my view for my CallScreen:

```
@{
    var item = (Rosh.QueueMe.Web.Models.MyQueue)TempData["QueueItem"];
}


    <table id="auto">
        <tr style="font-family:'Arial Rounded MT'">
            <th class="tickets">TICKETS</th>
            <th class="name">NAME</th>
            <th class="counter">COUNTER</th>
            <th class="service">SERVICE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>#@item.QueueNumber</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>Desk 1</td>
            <td>@item.ServiceId</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Its getting its data from my `TempData["QueueItem"];`

I tried using this code for my callscreen view, but for some reason its giving me an error that my `@item.QueueNumber`, `@item.Name` and `@item.ServiceId` does not exist in the current context anymore.

```
@if(TempData["QueueItem"] != null)
{
   var item = (Rosh.QueueMe.Web.Models.MyQueue)ViewBag.QueueItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need

```
ViewData.Clear();
```

Comment: do you mean `TempData.Clear();`

Comment: @CarloToribio yes exactly

Comment: yes I tried that 1 already but right after when I hit the `BtnFinish()` shoots me an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` , cause it's already null, I need to handle `null` in A proper way I guess.

Comment: whenever the form submitted the viewData and all page objects will be clear so you don't have to clear anything

Comment: it's clear in the back-end already thats for sure but in my front-end view it's still visible.

Comment: I think it's cashing related not something in code browser issue?

Comment: ohhh yea maybe thats it? how can I handle that

Comment: since you are using the viewbag or any dynamic objects type that means its not sensitive data so I believe you don't have to clear it any way you can do this using Jquery.Clear()  if you are using jquery library

Comment: do you know how can I do something like this in jquery? 
that when my `TempData["QueueNumber"]` is null then `clear()` my div?